# Is there a way to extract primitive fields from a Dictionary of objects in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
ObjectA
{
    int ID;
    string name;
}
```

I want to convert Dictionary to List where the strings in the list are the .name values of the ObjectAs in the dictionary.  Obviously I could manually iterate over the dictionary values and build the list that way, but I was hoping there'd be a simpler or faster way in C# / .NET.  A LINQ solution is fine, if it's simpler and faster than/as fast as:

```
List<string> aNames = new List<string>();
foreach(ObjectA a in DictionaryA.Values)
aNames.Add(a.name);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the non-query-expression form of Matthew's answer:

```
var names = DictionaryA.Values.Select(x => x.name).ToList();
```

(I tend not to use query expressions when I'm just doing a single select or a single where, especially if I also need to call another method such as `ToList`.)

Alternatively:

```
var names = DictionaryA.Select(x => x.Value.name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
(from val in DictionaryA.Values select val.name).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of ways to do this once you have a query:

```
IQueryable<string> query = DictionaryA.Values.Select(v => v.name);

//use the Constructor of List<T> that accepts IEnumerable<T>
List<string> aNames = new List<string>(query);
//
//or use the AddRange method for existing Lists
List<string> aNames = new List<string<();
aNames.AddRange(query);
//
//or use the Enumerable.ToList extension method
List<string> aNames = query.ToList();
```

Comment: That's not taking the "name" part though.

Comment: Take another look at the question. He doesn't want a list of dictionary's values. He wants a list of values of a property from each dictionary object.